# Qt5: This code compiles ok with msvc2012, yet gives error compiled with MinGW... Why?

Tags: c++, qt, visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors, mingw

I'm using Qt5.5.1 on Windows7 platform.
I have the following code that compiles (and runs) fine with msvc2012 build kit:

```
void MyDialog::accept()
{
    DataBase::instance()->logEventMessage(tr("Modified settings!"));
    close();
}
```

where *logEventMessage* is:

```
int  logEventMessage(QString & eventDescription);
```

When I switched to MinGW build kit, the compiler said:

> No matching function for call to DataBase::logEventMessage(QString)...

Well, fixing the issue was easy (compiler was expecting a QString& there):

```
void MyDialog::accept()
{
    QString text(tr("Modified settings!"));
    DataBase::instance()->logEventMessage(text);
    close();
}
```

**Yet, two things still puzzle me** :
1) Why initial code is compiling ok with msvc2012 build kit (while it's not compiling with MinGW)?
2) Which compiler is C++ "*correct*" ?... ;)

Comment: This is probably the MSVC extension that allows binding temporary object to non-const lvalue reference

Comment: To fix it, change the function to `int  logEventMessage(QString const & eventDescription);` (which it should have been in the first place, because you don't modify the message when logging it)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function takes a `QString&`.  This is an input and output parameter.  You construct it with a temporary, thus discarding any changes it makes.  Design wise this is suspect.

Probably you wanted to take a `const&`.

Under the C++ standard, you cannot bind a temporary to a reference to non-const.

MSVC has a non-conforming extension that prevents that error from occuring.

MSVC 2015 with the right compiler flags behaves properly.